# Dynamically connecting linked data with a condition

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to dynamically execute the Include and Where method in it to build a query in EF. From the input parameters there is only the name of the field for Include and the condition in the form of a string.

What I want without dynamics looks like:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
contextEF.Table1.Include(x => x.Field1.Where("c => c.Id == 500")).ToList();
```

Here is my extreme attempt at getting this code to work dynamically:

```
var nameField = "Field1";
var queryWhere = "c => c.Id == 500";

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(T).GetProperty(nameField));
var typeItem = typeof(T).GetProperty(nameField).PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();

var lambda = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(ParsingConfig.Default, typeItem, typeof(bool), queryWhere);
var expressionWhere =  Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new Type[] { typeItem }, lambda, property);
var expressionInclude = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(expressionWhere, parameter);

return queryable.Include(expressionInclude);
```

At the moment, I get errors with a call to the Where method and I can't move further:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.
```

It is clear from the error that it cannot find the Where method, where the parameter is string. But I don't understand how the program can prove that there is such a method =)

Comment: Are you pretty sure that this is what you need. it seems like you are trying to kill an ant with a bomb. Why not do a normal query and send that to your context?

Comment: Yes, it is required. The point is that there is a universal API / get / {object}.
Where object is conventionally the name of the table, you can also add the required fields to the parameter up to 2 nesting levels. From this, this need arose in order to load related data dynamically, since they are not always required.

Comment: In that case I would use sql query. write a method that builds your query in string,based on the parameters sent. Then execute the returned method on the table required. Most of the time if you write a complex Linq query and rewrite it in SQL the performance is significantly improved. Linq is not supposed to be used for complex/generic problems.

Comment: This request does not seem complicated, even trivial, but I could be wrong. I tried taking a LINQ query in my question and wrote a method to create a SQL query. The only thing I didn’t indicate in the question was another mandatory limitation - it’s LIMIT 20. I got an insignificant increase in performance with self-written SQL and in connection with the solution I found for myself, I stayed on EF Core in this exact API.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem, it all boiled down to the fact that I did not correctly specify the types for the .Include method, because there I have .Where, then the return type will be `IEnumerable`, and not `ICollection` as I expected.

```
var nameField = "Field1";
var queryWhere = "c => c.Id == 500";
var queryLambda = $"x => x.{nameField}.Where({queryWhere}).Take(20)";

Type typeEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(TProperty);
LambdaExpression lambdaInclude = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(typeof(T), typeEnumerable, queryLambda);
var includeQ = 
    Expression.Call(
        type: typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions),
        methodName: "Include",
        typeArguments: new Type[] { typeof(T), typeEnumerable },
        arguments: new[] {
            queryable.Expression,
            Expression.Quote(lambdaInclude)
        }
    );

queryable = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(includeQ);
```